# How do I add an SVN created descendent branch in git-svn?

Tags: svn, git, git-svn

I have two branches tracked in a Git repository from SVN.  Branch B was created in r6 in SVN by copying r5 of Branch A.  When I added Branch B to git-svn it only tracks back to r6.  I was expecting it to wire the Git commit of r6 on Branch B to the Git commit of r5 on Branch A.

I attempted `git rebase $(git svn find-rev r6 git-svn-BranchA) master-BranchB`, but it didn't work for me in this scenario since it breaks subsequent `git svn rebase` attempts.  It thinks it needs to merge and appears like it is attempting to rebase from git-svn-BranchA instead of git-svn-BranchB.

How do I add an SVN created descendent branch in git-svn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through hacking and re-hacking I had a breakthrough :)

1. Rebase the **remote** to the branch-point in SVN:

   ```
   git rebase $(git svn find-rev r5 git-svn-BranchA) git-svn-BranchB
   ```
2. Directly rewrite the SHA of the git-svn remote for Branch B:

   ```
   git rev-parse HEAD > .git/refs/remotes/git-svn-BranchB
   ```
3. Delete the branch tracking BranchB from SVN:

   ```
   git branch -D BranchB
   ```
4. Get a new tracking branch for BranchB from SVN:

   ```
   git checkout -b BranchB git-svn-BranchB
   ```
5. Rebuild the tracking information:

   ```
   git svn rebase
   ```

   You should see output like:

   ```
   Partial-rebuilding .git/svn/refs/remotes/git-svn-BranchB/.rev_map.########-####-####-####-############ ...
   Currently at 9 = ########################################
   r6 = ########################################
   r7 = ########################################
   r8 = ########################################
   r9 = ########################################
   Done rebuilding .git/svn/refs/remotes/git-svn-BranchB/.rev_map.########-####-####-####-############
   Current branch BranchB is up to date.
   ```

I really hope someone has a much less ugly version of step 2.  It seems like a grotesque hack to me.